# Python difflib: highlighting differences inline?

Tags: python, diff

When comparing similar lines, I want to highlight the differences on the same line:

```
a) lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
b) lorem foo ipsum dolor amet

lorem <ins>foo</ins> ipsum dolor <del>sit</del> amet
```

While difflib.HtmlDiff appears to do this sort of inline highlighting, it produces very verbose markup.

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find another class/method which does not operate on a line-by-line basis.

Am I missing anything?
Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

For your simple example:

```
import difflib
def show_diff(seqm):
    """Unify operations between two compared strings
seqm is a difflib.SequenceMatcher instance whose a & b are strings"""
    output= []
    for opcode, a0, a1, b0, b1 in seqm.get_opcodes():
        if opcode == 'equal':
            output.append(seqm.a[a0:a1])
        elif opcode == 'insert':
            output.append("<ins>" + seqm.b[b0:b1] + "</ins>")
        elif opcode == 'delete':
            output.append("<del>" + seqm.a[a0:a1] + "</del>")
        elif opcode == 'replace':
            raise NotImplementedError("what to do with 'replace' opcode?")
        else:
            raise RuntimeError("unexpected opcode")
    return ''.join(output)

>>> sm= difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", "lorem foo ipsum dolor amet")
>>> show_diff(sm)
'lorem<ins> foo</ins> ipsum dolor <del>sit </del>amet'
```

This works with strings. You should decide what to do with "replace" opcodes.

Comment: Thanks very much for this!
That's exactly the kind of sample I needed. I had no idea how to get started, but this illustrates it very well.
Again, many thanks!

Comment: +1 thanks for your example :) What would you suggest to do with replace optcodes?

Comment: Well, one suggestion would be to discover some 'replace' opcodes in the wild; the documentation says they can be produced, but I don't remember ever seeing any (IIRC I've only seen 'delete's followed by 'insert's). In any case, what to do with 'replace's is up to the OP.

Comment: the example on https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_opcodes contains replace opcodes.

Comment: For replace optcodes, I just appended both the action for insert, and delete's value.

Answer (score 9):

Here's an inline differ inspired by @tzot's [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/788780/37020) (also Python 3 compatible):

```
def inline_diff(a, b):
    import difflib
    matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, b)
    def process_tag(tag, i1, i2, j1, j2):
        if tag == 'replace':
            return '{' + matcher.a[i1:i2] + ' -> ' + matcher.b[j1:j2] + '}'
        if tag == 'delete':
            return '{- ' + matcher.a[i1:i2] + '}'
        if tag == 'equal':
            return matcher.a[i1:i2]
        if tag == 'insert':
            return '{+ ' + matcher.b[j1:j2] + '}'
        assert False, "Unknown tag %r"%tag
    return ''.join(process_tag(*t) for t in matcher.get_opcodes())
```

It's not perfect, for example, it would be nice to expand 'replace' opcodes to recognize the full word replaced instead of just the few different letters, but it's a good place to start.

Sample output:

```
>>> a='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing'
>>> b='Lorem bananas ipsum cabbage sit amet adipiscing'
>>> print(inline_diff(a, b))
Lorem{+  bananas} ipsum {dolor -> cabbage} sit amet{-  consectetur} adipiscing
```

Comment: I like how you process the 'replace' options.

Comment: I also like that you translated this to Python 3. I have now translated the original answer by tzot to Python 3 as well.

Comment: But is it really clearer to replace a loop with nested if with a method called in a Python comprehension?

Comment: @JosiahYoder fair question about the for loop vs comprehension. Since it's a style issue I'm unsure if there's a definitive answer beyond personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

[difflib.SequenceMatcher](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-objects) will operate on single lines. You can use the "opcodes" to determine how to change the first line to make it the second line.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand this - yet anyway, so I'll do more digging.
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the differences? Do you want HTML output or were you just using the HtmlDiff because it did in-line diffing?

Comment: While HTML output is my primary use case, HtmlDiff's output doesn't allow for easy reuse - that is, if it were simply inserting INS and DEL, that could then easily be transformed to whatever is needed further down the line.