# Python SequenceMatcher Overhead - 100% CPU utilization and very slow processing

Tags: python, difflib

I am using difflib to compare files in two directories (versions from consecutive years).
First, i am using filecmp to find files that have changed and then iteratively using difflib.SequenceMatcher to compare them and generate a html diff as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774316/python-difflib-highlighting-differences-inline).

However, I find that the program is taking too long to run and python is utilizing 100% CPU. On time profiling, i found that the **seqm.get_opcodes()** call which is taking all the time.

Any insight would be appreciated. 
Thanks !

Code:

```
#changed_set contains the files to be compared
for i in changed_set:
  oldLines = open(old_dir +"/" + i).read()
  newLines = open(new_dir +"/" + i).read()
  seqm = difflib.SequenceMatcher(lambda(x): x in string.whitespace, oldLines, newLines)
  opcodes = seqm.get_opcodes() #XXX: Lots of time spent in this !
  produceDiffs(seqm, opcodes)
  del seqm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is a different approach to the problem altogether: Try using a version-control system like git to investigate how the directory changed over the years.

Make a repository out of the first directory, then replace the contents with the next year's directory and commit that as a change.  (or move the .git directory to the next year's directory, to save on copying/deleting).  repeat.

Then run gitk, and you'll be able to see what changed between any two revisions of the tree.  Either just that a binary file changed, or with a diff for text files.

Comment: Why not just GNU diff then instead ?

Comment: @ChristopheD, Git uses diff to display differences.  However, it does a lot for you: it figures out which files haven't changed, and gives a diff on just the ones that have changed.  Then, gitk wraps all this in a friendly GUI where you can easily browse through different revisions.  This answer makes sense to me.

Comment: @PeterCordes: That is the nice solution - using GIT's metadata to get info about where the change was. However, it won't help me as currently all the previous years data is backed up in a file system and i don't have access to the CVS directly.

@ChristopheD: Actually i was using the diff command before from a shell script but then you get only details at line level (add/delete). With python difflib, you get precise info about which characters were inserted, deleted, replaced from an API. So, i switched over to python difflib.

Comment: There are other diff programs, e.g. wdiff for word-differences, not line-oriented.  You're probably close to having your python version working, though, so maybe you should stick with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the [`diff-match-patch`](https://pypi.org/project/diff-match-patch/) library, in my experience it can be 10 times faster.

EDIT: [Example my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388213/find-the-similarity-metric-between-two-strings/50102520#50102520)

```
from diff_match_patch import diff_match_patch

def compute_similarity_and_diff(text1, text2):
    dmp = diff_match_patch()
    dmp.Diff_Timeout = 0.0
    diff = dmp.diff_main(text1, text2, False)

    # similarity
    common_text = sum([len(txt) for op, txt in diff if op == 0])
    text_length = max(len(text1), len(text2))
    sim = common_text / text_length

    return sim, diff
```

Comment: providing an example would be more ideal