# Python filtering strings

Tags: python

I´m trying to make a python script to rename the subtitles file (.srt) with the filename of the video file corresponding to that episode, so when I open it in VLC the subtitles are already loaded.

So far I´ve succeeded in getting all the file names from the videos and subs into strings on two separate lists. Now I need to somehow pair the video string of episode 1 with the subtitle corresponding to the same episode.

I´ve tried in lots of differents ways but I always,most with regular patterns, but none has worked. 
Here´s an example of my code :

```
import glob 

videoPaths = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\tobia_000\Desktop\BBT\Video\*.mp4")
subsPaths = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\tobia_000\Desktop\BBT\Subs\*.srt") 
#With glob I sort the filenames of video and subs in separate variables

ep1 = []
ep2 = []
ep3 = []
#etc..
```

This is how the videoPaths and subsPaths variables would look like with the files I have. I dont have them all yet.

```
videoPath = ["The.Big.Bang.Theory.S05E24.HDTV.x264-LOL.mp4",
"The.Big.Bang.Theory.S05E19.HDTV.x264LOL.mp4",
"The.Big.Bang.Theory.S05E21.HDTV.x264-LOL.mp4"]

subsPath = ["The Big Bang Theory - 5x19 - The Weekend Vortex.720p HDTV.lol.en.srt",
"The Big Bang Theory - 5x21 - The Hawking Excitation.HDTV.LOL.en.srt",
"The Big Bang Theory - 5x24 - The Countdown Reflection.HDTV.LOL.en.srt"]
```

Comment: How the filenames look like ?

Comment: Is the extension the only difference? If so `zip(sorted(glob(path1), sorted(glob(path2))))`

Comment: apart from the above two questions. Are the filenames in `videoPaths and `subsPaths` ordered appropriately. ? Is all you want renaming the filename extentions or is there more ?

Comment: scratch that, the fact you are renaming means they cannot be the same or you would not need to rename.

Comment: It's pretty much a short in the dark but am thinking this other question would be useful for mathing video and subtitle files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388213/python-string-similarity-with-probability

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip) to make the pairs, *if* the sorted lists for `videoPaths` and `subsPaths` are correct in the they correspond to each other. ie First episode video and subtitles are both the first element of each list.

```
episodes = list(zip(videoPaths, subsPaths))
```

Edit: and since [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) returns result in an arbitrary order, sort before that.

```
episodes = list(zip(sorted(videoPaths), sorted(subsPaths)))
```

Comment: glob does not sort files so the chances of them being lined up is pretty slim