# How do you see if two variables have similar or same the characters?

Tags: python, string, variables

I am trying to see if a user can correctly guess a randomly generated four digit number, by using the in command, but if he gets some digits correct we notify the user.

```
number=random.randit(1000,9999)
number=str(number)
guess=input("Guess number")
if any (guess in number):
   print("Some digits correct")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the similarity percent between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388213/find-the-similarity-percent-between-two-strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your generator has to check for each digit in user guess:

```
number=randint(1000,9999)
number=str(number)
guess=input("Guess number")
if any (i in number for i in str(guess)):
    print("Some digits correct")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't require to see of the position of the digit is correct, one way would be to convert both `number` and `guess` into sets of digits. For example:

```
number = 2145
guess = 1078
set(str(number)) & set(str(guess))  # {'1'}
```

Otherwise, using the built-in [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html) might prove useful too.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that it doesn't work with repeated numbers : guessing `1111` correctly would only output 1 correct digit.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right! But it would still correctly identify that the user "gets some digits correct" of course. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created a random number cast it to a string.
Once you have casted the number to a string break the users input into an array of characters, then for each character check if the random number contains the users input character.
For every character that is guessed correctly increment a variable called correctly guessed.
Then you can give a percentage/weight of how correct the user was by dividing the number guessed correctly  divided by the array length of input guess.

Comment: You may also want to add some logic for repeating numbers in the randomly generated number for example:
Random number: 5556
Guess: 3456
The random number contains both 5 and 6 however not 3 and 4. I am not sure what rules you need to follow but i foresee repeating numbers being a problem if you must meet certain criteria.

Answer (score 0):

One way to compare the strings would be to count the occurence of every digit with a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter('9993')
Counter({'9': 3, '3': 1})
>>> Counter('3399')
Counter({'3': 2, '9': 2})
```

You can then iterate from 0 to 9 and find the minimum of the values from both counters:

```
>>> c1 = Counter('3399')
>>> c2 = Counter('9993')
>>> [(i,min(c1[str(i)], c2[str(i)])) for i in range(10)]
[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 1), (4, 0), (5, 0), (6, 0), (7, 0), (8, 0), (9, 2)]
```

It means that there is one `3` in common and two `9`s.