# Spell check for python input

Tags: python, loops, csv, spell-checking

I have a code which takes a user's input which is supposed to be a first and last name. My code then takes that input and searches a csv for projects and hours that the input name is associated to. The problem I'm running into is if I misspell or don't capitalize the first letter of each name the code will not work. Is there a function or a way out there where if the user inputs the first 3 letters right or something similar the code will automatically assume the correct spelling and change the input accordingly? I'm a very novice coder so any help would be great.

Here's my code for reference:

```
import csv

# I've used full name to avoid duplicate first names in report 
full_name = input('Enter your full name: ')

with open('Report1.csv') as csvfile:
    hour_summation = {}
    read_csv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in read_csv:
            if ' '.join((row[0], row[1])) == full_name.strip():
                hour_summation[row[2]] = hour_summation.get(row[2], 0) + int(float(row[3]))
print('This is {} full hours report:'.format(full_name))
for k, v in hour_summation.items():
    print(k + ': ' + str(v) + ' hours')
```

Comment: If the number of possible user names isn't too large, then create a list of them, normalize all by calling `lower()` on it (same normalization for a name to search) and take a look at `difflib.SequenceMatcher`, especially `ratio()`

Comment: You could look at fuzzy matching. https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/02/25/fuzzy-string-matching-in-python/

Comment: make all the strings lowercase before comparison should make things a lot easier, e.g. `full_name = input('Enter your full name: ').strip().lower()`, `' '.join((row[0], row[1])).lower()`, etc.

Comment: Possible Dupliate of [Find the similarity percent between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17388213/2823755)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.lower`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=lower#str.lower) on both the user input and the value from the csv to ignore case.

You can use [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=lower#str.startswith) to match the user input against the beginning of a value from the csv. You could also use [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) to detemrine if the user input is in a value from the csv.

Comment: This is great. I was able to use the lower() function. I'm still learning how to implement the startswith.

Comment: @stevenmiller You will probably want something like `if value_from_csv.startswith(user_input):`