# Django max similarity (TrigramSimilarity) from ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset, trigram

I have to implement a search function which will be fault tolerant.
Currently, I have the following situation:

***Models:***

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Illustration(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

***Query:***

```
queryset.annotate(similarity=TrigramSimilarity('name', fulltext) + TrigramSimilarity('tags__name', fulltext))
```

***Example data:***

Illustrations:

```
ID |  Name  |        Tags       |
---|--------|-------------------|
 1 | "Dog"  | "Animal", "Brown" |
 2 | "Cat"  | "Animals"         |
```

Illustration has Tags:

```
ID_Illustration | ID_Tag |
----------------|--------|
       1        |    1   |
       1        |    2   |
       2        |    3   |
```

Tags:

```
ID_Tag |   Name   |
-------|----------|
   1   |  Animal  |
   2   |  Brown   |
   3   |  Animals |
```

When I run the query with `"Animal"`, the similarity for `"Dog"` should be higher than for `"Cat"`, as it is a perfect match.
Unfortunately, both tags are considered together somehow.
Currently, it looks like it's concatenating the tags in a single string and then checks for similarity:

```
TrigramSimilarity("Animal Brown", "Animal") => X
```

But I would like to adjust it in a way that I will get the highest similarity between an `Illustration` instance name and its tags:

```
Max([
    TrigramSimilarity('Name', "Animal"), 
    TrigramSimilarity("Tag_1", "Animal"), 
    TrigramSimilarity("Tag_2", "Animal"),
]) => X
```

---

Edit1: I'm trying to query all Illustration, where either the title or one of the tags has a similarity bigger than X.

Edit2: Additional example:

> fulltext = 'Animal'
>
> TrigramSimilarity('Animal Brown', fulltext) => x
>   TrigramSimilarity('Animals', fulltext) => y
>
> Where x < y
>
> But what I want is actually
>
> TrigramSimilarity(Max(['Animal', 'Brown]), fulltext) => x (Similarity
>   to Animal) TrigramSimilarity('Animals', fulltext) => y
>
> Where x > y

Comment: Can you precise from which model you are doing the queryset? Also, what are those example data ? the name+id of the illustration and the tags ?

Comment: Question adjusted

Comment: Edit 2 added (for more details).

Comment: is `TrigramSimilarity` a python function or does it translate to SQL? If it's python, I don't think you can use it in the `annotate` call as you're trying to do.

Comment: TrigramSimilarity is part of the Django Framework ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/), but it requires a PostgreSQL Database (won't work with SQLite) with the pg_trgm extension activated.

Comment: @Lukas can I ask if you've tried my solution ?

Comment: @Paolo: I didn't had the time so far, but I will try it in the evening and give you feedback. Sorry, but I already started applying Johns approach, before you posted your solution.

Comment: @Lukas the next time you choose an answer to your question, accept it immediately, you will avoid people taking the time to write a solution that will not be taken into consideration by you.

Anyway, I'm waiting your feedback about my solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot break up the `tags__name` (at least I don't know a way).
 
From your examples, I can assume 2 possible solutions (1st solution is not strictly using Django):

---

1. **Not everything needs to pass strictly through Django**
   We have Python powers, so let's use them:

   Let us compose the query first:

   ```
   from difflib import SequenceMatcher

   from django.db.models import Q

   def create_query(fulltext):
       illustration_names = Illustration.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
       tag_names = Tag.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
       query = []

       for name in illustration_names:
           score = SequenceMatcher(None, name, fulltext).ratio()
           if score == 1:
               # Perfect Match for name
               return [Q(name=name)]

            if score >= THRESHOLD:
               query.append(Q(name=name))

       for name in tag_names:
           score = SequenceMatcher(None, name, fulltext).ratio()
           if score == 1:
               # Perfect Match for name
               return [Q(tags__name=name)]

            if score >= THRESHOLD:
               query.append(Q(tags__name=name))

       return query
   ```

   Then to create your queryset:

   ```
   from functools import reduce # Needed only in python 3
   from operator import or_

   queryset = Illustration.objects.filter(reduce(or_, create_query(fulltext)))
   ```

   **Decode the above:**

   *We are checking every `Illustration` and `Tag` name against our `fulltext` and we are composing a query with every name that it's similarity passes the `THRESHOLD`.*

   - [`SequenceMatcher`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher) method compares sequences and returns a ratio `0 < ratio < 1` where 0 indicates **No-Match** and 1 indicates **Perfect-Match**. Check this answer for another usage example: [Find the similarity percent between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388213/find-the-similarity-percent-between-two-strings) (*Note:* There are other strings comparing modules as well, find one that suits you)
   - [`Q()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) Django objects, allow the creation of complex queries (more on the linked docs).
   - With the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#module-operator) and [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) we transform a list of `Q()` objects to an OR separated query argument: 
     `Q(name=name_1) | Q(name=name_2) | ... | Q(tag_name=tag_name_1) | ...`

   **Note:**
   You need to define an acceptable `THRESHOLD`.
   As you can imagine this will be a bit slow but it is to be expected when you need to do a "fuzzy" search.

---

2. **(The Django Way:)** 
   Use a query with a high similarity threshold and order the queryset by this similarity rate:

   ```
   queryset.annotate(
       similarity=Greatest(
           TrigramSimilarity('name', fulltext), 
           TrigramSimilarity('tags__name', fulltext)
       )).filter(similarity__gte=threshold).order_by('-similarity')
   ```

   **Decode the above:**

   - [`Greatest()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/database-functions/#greatest) accepts an aggregation (not to be confused with the Django method `aggregate`) of expressions or of model fields and returns the max item.
   - `TrigramSimilarity(word, search)` returns a rate between 0 and 1. The closer the rate is to 1, the more similar the `word` is to `search`.
   - `.filter(similarity__gte=threshold)`, will filter similarities lower than the `threshold`.
   - `0 < threshold < 1`. You can set the threshold to `0.6` which is pretty high (consider that the default is `0.3`). **You can play around with that to tune your performance.**
   - Finally, order the queryset by the `similarity` rate in a descending order.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working like this, as TrigramSimilarity only works like this: TrigramSimilarity(columnName, searchString). Therefore it would search for a column labeled as "Animal", "Brown" or "Animals".

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it out. But it looks different to what I had before, as it only allows me to filter, but not to sort depending on the result or am I wrong?

Comment: @Lukas you cannot sort as it is but with a slight modification you could do it (`sort` the name lists before the composition of the query).

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue as you described in option 1. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @Lukas Good to know :)

Answer (score 4):

I solved it using only [TrigramSimilarity](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#trigramsimilarity), [Max](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#max) and [Greatest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#greatest).

*I populated some data as in your question:*

```
from illustrations.models import Illustration, Tag
Tag.objects.bulk_create([Tag(name=t) for t in ['Animal', 'Brown', 'Animals']])
Illustration.objects.bulk_create([Illustration(name=t) for t in ['Dog', 'Cat']])
dog=Illustration.objects.get(name='Dog')
cat=Illustration.objects.get(name='Cat')
animal=Tag.objects.get(name='Animal')
brown=Tag.objects.get(name='Brown')
animals=Tag.objects.get(name='Animals')
dog.tags.add(animal, brown)
cat.tags.add(animals)
```

*I imported all necessary functions and initialized `fulltext`:*

```
from illustrations.models import Illustration
from django.contrib.postgres.search import TrigramSimilarity
from django.db.models.functions import Greatest
from django.db.models import Max
fulltext = 'Animal'
```

**Then I executed the query:**

```
Illustration.objects.annotate(
    max_similarity=Greatest(
        Max(TrigramSimilarity('tags__name', fulltext)),
        TrigramSimilarity('name', fulltext)
    )
).values('name', 'max_similarity')
```

**With this results:**

```
<QuerySet [{'name': 'Dog', 'max_similarity': 1.0}, {'name': 'Cat', 'max_similarity': 0.666667}]>
```

*This is the SQL query exceuted from PostgreSQL:*

```
SELECT "illustrations_illustration"."name", GREATEST(MAX(SIMILARITY("illustrations_tag"."name", 'Animal')), SIMILARITY("illustrations_illustration"."name", 'Animal')) AS "max_similarity"
FROM "illustrations_illustration"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "illustrations_illustration_tags" ON ("illustrations_illustration"."id" = "illustrations_illustration_tags"."illustration_id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "illustrations_tag" ON ("illustrations_illustration_tags"."tag_id" = "illustrations_tag"."id")
GROUP BY "illustrations_illustration"."id", SIMILARITY("illustrations_illustration"."name", 'Animal')
```

You can use the `max_similarity` annotation to filter or order your results.