# Doing something if variable matches percentage of list element

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry if I explain this poorly in advance. I'm looking to output something if a variable matches a certain percentage of a list element. For example:

```
sentencelst = ['It is a very nice day', 'How are you', 'How is the weather', 'Have a great day']

matchedsentence = 'It is a nice day'

if matchedsentence is 75% similar in sentencelst:
    print('75% match')
else:
    print('less than 75% match')
    continue
```

The end goal is that if `matchedsentence` contains 75% of the words of any of the elements in `sentencelst` it will do a something.Sorry again if you can't understand the question I'm having trouble understanding it myself.

Comment: Maybe read about [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: You can also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388213/find-the-similarity-percent-between-two-strings).

Comment: What happens if a word is repeated in your list? Suppose `sentenceList` contained `"The weather is the warmest today"` and `matchedsentence = 'The weather today'` - is that a 50% match (3 out of 6) or a 60% match (3 out of 5)? Also is your condition case sensitive? What about punctuation?

Comment: I think you're looking for something similar to the Jaccard similarity/distance. That's the length of the intersection divided by the length of the union. Another topic to google.

Comment: It isn't case sensitive, and punctuation doesn't matter either. That is an oversight I didn't think about so thanks, the two links above about Liechtenstein distance helped me a lot so i'm gonna look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `fuzzywuzzy` package:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

sentencelst = ['It is a very nice day', 'How are you', 'How is the weather', 'Have a great day']

matchedsentence = 'It is a nice day'

for sentence in sentencelst:
    if fuzz.ratio(sentence, matchedsentence) > 75:
        print('75% match')
    else:
        print('less than 75% match')
        continue
```