# Drop Dataframe Rows Based on a Similarity Measure Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I want to eliminate repeated rows in my dataframe.

I know that that drop_duplicates() method works for dropping rows with identical subcolumn values. However I want to drop rows that aren't identical but similar. For example, I have the following two rows:

```
       Title        |   Area   |    Price
Apartment at Boston    100         150000
Apt at Boston          105         149000
```

I want to be able to eliminate these two columns based on some similarity measure, such as if Title, Area, and Price differ by less than 5%. Say, I could delete rows whose similarity measure > 0.95. This would be particularly useful for large data sets, instead of manually inspecting row by row. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It is hard to compare the abbreviation with whole word , even soundex  will return the different code

Comment: Yeah I was thinking maybe counting identical words and getting ratio of identical words/total. Similarly, getting the percentage difference between Area and Price values. I am not sure how to implement this though.

Comment: Check if fuzzywuzzy will help. https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function using difflib. I got the similar function from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388213/find-the-similarity-metric-between-two-strings)  You may also want to check out some of the answers on that page to determine the best similarity metric for your use case.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Title':['Apartment at Boston','Apt at Boston'],
                  'Area':[100,105],
                  'Price':[150000,149000]})

def string_ratio(df,col,ratio):
    from difflib import SequenceMatcher
    import numpy as np
    def similar(a, b):
        return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
    ratios = []
    for i, x in enumerate(df[col]):
        a = np.array([similar(x, row) for row in df[col]])
        a = np.where(a < ratio)[0]
        ratios.append(len(a[a != i])==0)
    return pd.Series(ratios)

def numeric_ratio(df,col,ratio):
    ratios = []
    for i, x in enumerate(df[col]):
        a = np.array([min(x,row)/max(x,row) for row in df[col]])
        a = np.where(a<ratio)[0]
        ratios.append(len(a[a != i])==0)
    return pd.Series(ratios)

mask = ~((string_ratio(df1,'Title',.95))&(numeric_ratio(df1,'Area',.95))&(numeric_ratio(df1,'Price',.95)))

df1[mask]
```

It should be able to weed out most of the similar data, though you might want to tweak the string_ratio function if it doesn't suite you case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How would you alter this code in the case where you want to maintain the first repeated row?

Answer (score 1):

See if this meets your needs

```
Title = ['Apartment at Boston', 'Apt at Boston', 'Apt at Chicago','Apt at   Seattle','Apt at Seattle','Apt at Chicago']
Area = [100, 105, 100, 102,101,101]
Price = [150000, 149000,150200,150300,150000,150000]
data = dict(Title=Title, Area=Area, Price=Price)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=data.keys())
```

The df created is as below

```html
Title  Area  Price
0  Apartment at Boston  100  150000
1  Apt at Boston  105  149000
2  Apt at Chicago  100  150200
3  Apt at Seattle  102  150300
4  Apt at Seattle  101  150000
5  Apt at Chicago  101  150000
```

Now, we run the code as below

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
def fuzzy_compare(a,b):
    val=fuzz.partial_ratio(a,b)
    return val
tl = df["Title"].tolist()
itered=1
i=0
def do_the_thing(i):
    itered=i+1    
    while itered < len(tl):
        val=fuzzy_compare(tl[i],tl[itered])
        if val > 80:
            if abs((df.loc[i,'Area'])/(df.loc[itered,'Area']))>0.94 and abs((df.loc[i,'Area'])/(df.loc[itered,'Area']))<1.05:
                if abs((df.loc[i,'Price'])/(df.loc[itered,'Price']))>0.94 and abs((df.loc[i,'Price'])/(df.loc[itered,'Price']))<1.05:
                    df.drop(itered,inplace=True)
                    df.reset_index()
                    pass
                else:
                    pass
            else:
                pass            
       else:
            pass
       itered=itered+1    
while i < len(tl)-1:
    try:
        do_the_thing(i)
        i=i+1
    except:
        i=i+1
        pass
else:
    pass
```

the output is df as below. Repeating Boston & Seattle items are removed when fuzzy match is more that 80 & the values of Area & Price are within 5% of each other.

```html
Title  Area  Price
0  Apartment at Boston  100  150000
2  Apt at Chicago  100  150200
3  Apt at Seattle  102  150300
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How would you alter the code to allow multiple (>2) repeated rows and we just want to keep one of them?

Comment: This already does that. It will retain the 1st instance only irrespective of how many more similar rows are there. I checked by adding 3 of 'Chicago' and only the first one remains. Please check.

Comment: I have updated the code a bit more, to catch an exception.Try this.