# Sequences’ Similarity Matching in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, similarity

I tried searching the answer in SO but didnt find any help.

Here is what I´m trying to do:

 I have a dataframe (here is a small example of it):

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 5, 'AADDEEEEIILMNORRTU'], [2, 5, 'AACEEEEGMMNNTT'], [3, 5, 'AAACCCCEFHIILMNNOPRRRSSTTUUY'], [4, 5, 'DEEEGINOOPRRSTY'], [5, 5, 'AACCDEEHHIIKMNNNNTTW'], [6, 5, 'ACEEHHIKMMNSSTUV'], [7, 5, 'ACELMNOOPPRRTU'], [8, 5, 'BIT'], [9, 5, 'APR'], [10, 5, 'CDEEEGHILLLNOOST'], [11, 5, 'ACCMNO'], [12, 5, 'AIK'], [13, 5, 'CCHHLLOORSSSTTUZ'], [14, 5, 'ANNOSXY'], [15, 5, 'AABBCEEEEHIILMNNOPRRRSSTUUVY']],columns=['PartnerId','CountryId','Name'])
```

My goal is to find the `PartnerId`s which `Name` is similar at least up to a certain `ratio`.

Additionally I only want to compare `PartnerId`s that have the same `CountryId`. The matching `PartnerId`s should be appended to a list and finally written in a new column in the dataframe.

Here is my try:

```
itemDict = {item[0]: {'CountryId': item[1], 'Name': item[2]} for item in df.values}

from difflib import SequenceMatcher
def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

def calculate_similarity(x,itemDict):
    own_name = x['Name']
    country_id = x['CountryId']
    matching_ids = []
    for k, v in itemDict.items():

        if k != x['PartnerId']:
            if v['CountryId'] == country_id:

                ratio = similar(own_name,v['Name'])


                if ratio > 0.7:

                    matching_ids.append(k)
    return matching_ids

df['Similar_IDs'] = df.apply(lambda x: calculate_similarity(x,itemDict),axis=1)
print(df)
```

The output is:

```
    PartnerId  CountryId                          Name Similar_IDs
0           1          5            AADDEEEEIILMNORRTU          []
1           2          5                AACEEEEGMMNNTT          []
2           3          5  AAACCCCEFHIILMNNOPRRRSSTTUUY        [15]
3           4          5               DEEEGINOOPRRSTY        [10]
4           5          5          AACCDEEHHIIKMNNNNTTW          []
5           6          5              ACEEHHIKMMNSSTUV          []
6           7          5                ACELMNOOPPRRTU          []
7           8          5                           BIT          []
8           9          5                           APR          []
9          10          5              CDEEEGHILLLNOOST         [4]
10         11          5                        ACCMNO          []
11         12          5                           AIK          []
12         13          5              CCHHLLOORSSSTTUZ          []
13         14          5                       ANNOSXY          []
14         15          5  AABBCEEEEHIILMNNOPRRRSSTUUVY         [3]
```

My questions now are:

1.) Is there a more efficient way to compute it? I have about 20.000 rows now and a lot more in the near future.

2.) Is it possible to get "rid" of the itemDict and do it directly from the dataframe?

3.) Is another distance measure maybe better to use?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the module `difflib`. First, you need to make a cartesian product of all strings by joining the table to itself using outer join:

```
cols = ['Name', 'CountryId', 'PartnerId']
df = df[cols].merge(df[cols], on='CountryId', how='outer')    
df = df.query('PartnerId_x != PartnerId_y')
```

In the next step you can apply the function from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17388505/8973620) and filter out all matches:

```
def match(x):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, x[0], x[1]).ratio()

match = df.apply(match, axis=1) > 0.7
df.loc[match, ['PartnerId_x', 'Name_x', 'PartnerId_y']]
```

Output:

```
     PartnerId_x                        Name_x  PartnerId_y
44             3  AAACCCCEFHIILMNNOPRRRSSTTUUY           15
54             4               DEEEGINOOPRRSTY           10
138           10              CDEEEGHILLLNOOST            4
212           15  AABBCEEEEHIILMNNOPRRRSSTUUVY            3
```

If you don't have enough memory you can try to iterate over the rows of a data frame:

```
lst = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if SequenceMatcher(None, row['Name_x'], row['Name_y']).ratio() > 0.7:
        lst.append(row[['PartnerId_x', 'Name_x', 'PartnerId_y']])

pd.concat(lst, axis=1).T
```

Comment: Looks good so far! in your description you are writing "inner join" but then using "Outer" join afterwards. I guess it doesn´t matter anyway!

Comment: @mgruber I meant self join. Thank you for correction.

Comment: I tried to use the code for my 19.053 rows and ended up getting a ```MemoryError```.

Comment: @mgruber It looks like you don't have enough RAM.

Comment: @MykolaZotko the merge takes around 1 minute already. The Error is thrown during the matching. The length of the merged dataframe is 131.044.638 which is obviously way to much to work on for my 'poor' machine. I thought about if there is a way to first order the df based on CountryId and Name and then only merge it with 5 entries above and below. The other >19k rows will not be a match anyway.

Comment: @mgruber You can try to iterate over the merged data frame (s. my answer)

Comment: @mgruber You can also use the function `product` from `itertools` to build a cartesian product. It produces a generator and doesn't need to save the whole data frame.

Comment: @thanks for your suggestion. I will try it now! Do you have an idea how I can try what I suggested above? Only merge each row with +/- 5 rows above and below?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time now. You can make another question. I see that you work as a Data Scientist. Maybe your boss has a position for me. I am currently looking for a job in Germany

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59784767/pandas-merge-one-dataframe-with-itself-only-partially Thank you for your help! Unfortunately all positions are taken.