# Pandas - Merge one dataframe with itself only partially

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

This is a follow up question from the following Question:
[Pandas Similarity Matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59783162/pandas-similarity-matching)

The ultimate goal of the first question was to find a way to similarity match each row with another if they have the same `CountryId`.

Here is the sample dataframe:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 5, 'AADDEEEEIILMNORRTU'], [2, 5, 'AACEEEEGMMNNTT'], [3, 5, 'AAACCCCEFHIILMNNOPRRRSSTTUUY'], [4, 5, 'DEEEGINOOPRRSTY'], [5, 5, 'AACCDEEHHIIKMNNNNTTW'], [6, 5, 'ACEEHHIKMMNSSTUV'], [7, 5, 'ACELMNOOPPRRTU'], [8, 5, 'BIT'], [9, 5, 'APR'], [10, 5, 'CDEEEGHILLLNOOST'], [11, 5, 'ACCMNO'], [12, 5, 'AIK'], [13, 5, 'CCHHLLOORSSSTTUZ'], [14, 5, 'ANNOSXY'], [15, 5, 'AABBCEEEEHIILMNNOPRRRSSTUUVY']],columns=['PartnerId','CountryId','Name'])
```

The answer in other thread was good for the question but I ended up getting computational problems. My real source contains >19.000 rows and will be even bigger in the future.

The answer suggested to `merge` the dataframe with each self to compare it with every other row that has the same `CountryId`:

```
df = df.merge(df, on='CountryId', how='outer')
```

Even for the small example of 15 rows provided above we will end up with 225 merged rows. For the whole dataset I ended up with 131.044.638 rows which made my RAM refuse to work. Therefore I need to think of a better way to `merge`the two dataframes.

As I´m doing a similarity check I was wondering if there is a possibility to:

1. Sort the dataframe based on the `CountryId` and the `Name`
2. Only merge each row with the +/- 3 rows connecting. E.g. After sorting Row 1 will only be merged with (2,3 & 4) as this is the first
       row., Row 2 will only be merged with (1, 3, 4, 5) and so on.

Like this I will have similar names almost next to each other and names "further away" will not be similar anyway. Therefore its not needed to check the similarity of them.

Comment: cross join will have those type of problem

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for my problem that is taking the 3 rows before (if existing) and after.

```
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by=['CountryId','Name']).reset_index(drop=True)
new_sorted = pd.Series()
min = -3
max = 3
for s in list(range(min,max+1,1)):
    if s == min:
        new_sorted = sorted_df['PartnerId'].astype(str).shift(s,fill_value='A').rename('MatchingID')
    elif s != 0:
        new_sorted = new_sorted + '-' + sorted_df['PartnerId'].astype(str).shift(s,fill_value='A').rename('MatchingID')


match = sorted_df.merge(new_sorted,left_index=True,right_index=True)

matching_df = []
for index, row in match.iterrows():
    row_values = row.tolist()
    matching_df += [row_values[0:-1] + [int(w)] for w in row_values[-1].split('-') if w != 'A']
```

If anyone can come up with a better idea I would be glad to hear it!