# How to calculate similarity percentage between multiple strings in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, similarity

I know this question has been asked several times but I could not find the satisfying answer, so I attempt to try to ask one more time. I have 6 string lists (A-F), which contains codename.

```
A=('com','kaw','has','lot','sfa','alm','wah')
B=('bac','blm','cba','com','dol','has','kaw','lis','lot','lsv','mco','mil','oby','sfa','wah')
C=('fri','com','dol','emo','has','kaw','lot','mco','moo','pob','rag','sfa','skj','wah')
D=('com','dol','kaw','lot','lsv','mil','sfa')
E=('com','has','kaw','lot','mco','pob','rru','sfa','wah')
F='fri','bet','bip','blt','brz','cnt','dol','kaw','lec','mas','rnj','rru','sfa','skj','swo','wah','yft')
```

I want to calculate the similarity percentage (SP) between A and others. The result should be a table, where each List contains SP to other list.
Like this

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F
A  
B
C
D
E
F
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388213/find-the-similarity-metric-between-two-strings

Comment: First you need to define what similarity percentage means.