# Compare each element of CSV file to every element of a different CSV file, and find the most similar elements

Tags: python-3.x, csv, cosine-similarity

I have two CSV files which I need to compare. The first one is called SAP.csv, and the second is SAPH.csv.

SAP.csv has these cells:

```
Notification    Description
5000000001      Detailed Inspection of Masts (2100mm) (3
5000000002      Ceremonial Awnings-Survey and Load Test
5000000003      HPA-Carry out 4000 hour service routine
5000000004      UxE 8 in Number Temperature Probs for C
5000000005      Overhaul valves
```

...while, SAPH.csv has these cells:

```
Notification   Description
4000000015     Detailed Inspection of Masts (2100mm) (3
4000000016     Ceremonial Awnings-Survey and Load Test
4000000017     HPA-Carry out 8000 hour service routine
4000000018     UxE 8 in Number Temperature Probs for C
4000000019     Represerve valves
4000000020     STW System
```

They are similar, but some lines, like the fourth, (*HPA-Carry out **4000** hour service routine vs. HPA-Carry out **8000** hour service routine*), are slightly different.

I want to compare each value of SAP.csv against every value of SAPH.csv, and, using cosine similarity, find the most similar lines, so that the output would look something like this (the similarity percentages here are just examples, not what they would actually be):

```
Description
Detailed Inspection of Masts (2100mm) (3 - 100%
Ceremonial Awnings-Survey and Load Test  - 100%
HPA-Carry out 4000 hour service routine  - 85%
UxE 8 in Number Temperature Probs for C  - 90%
Overhaul valves                          - 0%
```

Post answer edit

runfile('C:/Users/andrew.stillwell2/.spyder-py3/Estimating Test.py', wdir='C:/Users/andrew.stillwell2/.spyder-py3')

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

```
runfile('C:/Users/andrew.stillwell2/.spyder-py3/Estimating Test.py', wdir='C:/Users/andrew.stillwell2/.spyder-py3')
```

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile

```
execfile(filename, namespace)
```

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile

```
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
```

File "C:/Users/andrew.stillwell2/.spyder-py3/Estimating Test.py", line 31, in

```
similarity_score = similar(job, description) # Get their similarity
```

File "C:/Users/andrew.stillwell2/.spyder-py3/Estimating Test.py", line 14, in similar

```
similarity = 1-textdistance.Cosine(qval=2).distance(a, b)
```

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textdistance\algorithms\base.py", line 173, in distance

```
return self.maximum(*sequences) - self.similarity(*sequences)
```

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textdistance\algorithms\base.py", line 176, in similarity

```
return self(*sequences)
```

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textdistance\algorithms\token_based.py", line 175, in **call**

```
return intersection / pow(prod, 1.0 / len(sequences))
```

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

2nd Edit because of solution to the above

So the original request had just two outputs - Description and Similairty score.

Description comes from SAP
Similarity comes from the textdistance calc

Can the solution be ammended to the following

Notifcation (this is a 10 digit number which is in the SAP file)
Description (as it currently is)
Similarity (as it currently is)
Notification (this number comes from the SAPH file and would be the one which provides the similarity score)

So an example row output would like this

80000115360 Additional Materials FWD Rope Guard 86.24% 7123456789

This would be along columns A, B, C, D

A, B comes from SAP
C is calculated
D comes from SAPH

Edit 3

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile

```
execfile(filename, namespace)
```

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile

```
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
```

File "C:/Users/andrew.stillwell2/.spyder-py3/Est Test 2.py", line 16, in

```
SAP = pd.read_csv('H:\Documents/Python/Import into Python/SAP/SAP.csv', dtype={'Notification':'string'})
```

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 702, in parser_f

```
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
```

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 429, in _read

```
parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
```

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 895, in **init**

```
self._make_engine(self.engine)
```

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1122, in _make_engine

```
self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
```

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1853, in **init**

```
self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
```

File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 490, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.**cinit**

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\common.py", line 2017, in pandas_dtype

```
dtype))
```

TypeError: data type 'string' not understood

Post edit 4 - 25/10/20

Hi, so getting the same error as before I think

This email may contain proprietary information of BAE Systems and/or third parties.

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile

```
execfile(filename, namespace)
```

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile

```
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
```

File "C:/Users/andrew.stillwell2/.spyder-py3/Est Test 2.py", line 16, in

```
SAP = pd.read_csv('H:\Documents/Python/Import into Python/SAP/SAP.csv', dtype={'Notification':'string'}, delimiter=",", engine="python")
```

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 702, in parser_f

```
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
```

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 435, in _read

```
data = parser.read(nrows)
```

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1139, in read

```
ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
```

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2421, in read

```
data = self._convert_data(data)
```

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2487, in _convert_data

```
clean_conv, clean_dtypes)
```

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1705, in _convert_to_ndarrays

```
cvals = self._cast_types(cvals, cast_type, c)
```

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1808, in _cast_types

```
copy=True, skipna=True)
```

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py", line 623, in astype_nansafe

```
dtype = pandas_dtype(dtype)
```

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\common.py", line 2017, in pandas_dtype

```
dtype))
```

TypeError: data type 'string' not understood

I picked up on your bit about the delimiter so I uploaded a csv file to repl.it and it looks as though "," is the delimiter.

Therefore have altered the code to suit. When I did that on repl.it it worked.

This is the code I am using

import textdistance

import pandas as pd

def similar(a, b): # adapted from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63838615/8402369

```
similarity = 1-textdistance.Cosine(qval=2).distance(a, b)

return similarity * 100
```

## Read the CSVs

SAP = pd.read_csv('H:\Documents/Python/Import into Python/SAP/SAP.csv', dtype={'Notification':'string'}, delimiter=",", engine="python")

SAPH = pd.read_csv('H:\Documents/Python/Import into Python/SAP/SAP_History.csv', dtype={'Notification':'string'}, delimiter=",", engine="python")

## Create a pandas dataframe to store the output. The column 'Description' is populated with the values of SAP['Description']

scores = pd.DataFrame(SAP['Description'], columns = ['Notification (SAP)','Description', 'Similarity', 'Notification (SAPH)'])

## Temporary variable to store the highest similarity score

highest_score = 0

desc = 0

## Iterate though SAP['Description']

for job in SAP['Description']:

highest_score = 0 # Reset highest_score in each iteration

for description in SAPH['Description']: # Iterate through SAPH['Description']

```
similarity_score = similar(job, description) # Get their similarity



if(similarity_score > highest_score): # Check if the similarity is higher than the already saved similarity. If so, update highest_score with the new values

  highest_score = similarity_score

  desc = str(description)

if(similarity_score == 100): # If it's a perfect match, don't bother continuing to search.

  break
```

## Update the dataframe 'scores' with highest_score and other values

## print(SAPH['Description'][SAPH['Description'] == desc])

scores['Notification (SAP)'][scores['Description'] == job] = SAP['Notification'][SAP['Description'] == job]

scores['Similarity'][scores['Description'] == job] = f'{highest_score}%'

scores['Notification (SAPH)'][scores['Description'] == job] = SAPH['Notification'][SAPH['Description'] == desc]

print(scores)

## Output it to Scores.csv without the index column

with open('./Scores.csv', 'w') as file:

```
file.write(scores.__repr__())
```

Which is being run on Spyder (Python 3.7)

Comment: Please provide sample data for each csv so we can test. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mike, how do I add csv files to the post?

Comment: Just update your post and paste in 10 sample rows from each file (including headers)

Comment: Apologies Mike, when I go to paste it adds a picture which the server rejects. Obviously something really simple I am missing

Comment: Paste into notepad first then copy\paste to SO.

Comment: Done, but have had to press return as when I have them striaght underneath one another they so in a continuous string

Comment: No problem. Paste without extra returns. You can click the code format button `{}` or just paste the data and let someone else do the format.

Comment: @Mike67 _ugh_, why would you encourage OP to _let someone else do the format_ and not do it yourself instead of giving OP the [link to the help?](/help/formatting)

Comment: How did you get the numbers you get? `HPA-Carry out 4000 hour service routine` and 
`UxE 8 in Number Temperature Probs for C` both have a 100% match in SAPH.csv if I've understood correctly that you want to match lines for similarity.

Comment: Hi @PranavHosangadi, these are essentially work orders. I am trying to come up eventually with a list of what work orders we have carried out on previous projects and to what level of simillairty they have, So those two you have said are 100% done before so we can look up actuals on it. I am trying to do a very small sample set as the full version will have 1,000s of lines. . I am then look to tabulate the the cosine percentages in 5% steps 0-5%, 6-10%, 11-15% etc with counts of how similar the work is

Comment: I have made a c&p error the 4000 hour service should have been 8000 in SAPH which I have now changed

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi - Yes - I normally would ask the OP to format the answer, but if it's a problem, I figured I can easily do it. When I said 'someone else', I meant me (unless someone gets to it first)

Comment: Could you orovide the answer then please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@George_Pipas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63838615/8402369) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388213/) demonstrates an example using the library `textdistance` (I'm paraphrasing part of his answer here):

> A solution is to work with the `textdistance` library. I will provide an example of `Cosine Similarity`
>
> ```py
> import textdistance
> 1-textdistance.Cosine(qval=2).distance('Apple', 'Appel')
> ```
>
> and we get:
>
> ```
> 0.5
> ```

So, we can create a similarity finding function:

```py
def similar(a, b):
    similarity = 1-textdistance.Cosine(qval=2).distance(a, b)     
    return similarity
```

Depending on the similarity, this'll output a number closer to 1, if `a` and `b` are more similar, and it'll output a number closer to 0 if they aren't. So if `a === b`, the output will be `1`, but if `a !== b`, the output will be less than 1.

To get percentages, you just need to multiply the output by 100. Like this:

```py
def similar(a, b): # adapted from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63838615/8402369
    similarity = 1-textdistance.Cosine(qval=2).distance(a, b) 
    return similarity * 100
```

CSV files can be read pretty easily with `pandas`:

```py
# Read the CSVs
SAP = pd.read_csv('SAP.csv') 
SAPH = pd.read_csv('SAPH.csv')
```

We create another [pandas dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) to store the results we'll compute in:

```py
# Create a pandas dataframe to store the output. The column 'SAP' is populated with the values of SAP['Description']
scores = pd.DataFrame({'SAP': SAP['Description']}, columns = ['SAP', 'SAPH', 'Similarity'])
```

Now, we iterate through `SAP['Description']` and `SAPH['Description']`, compare each element against each other element, compute their similarity, and save the highest to `scores`.

```py
# Temporary variable to store both the highest similarity score, and the 'SAPH' value the score was computed with
highest_score = {"score": 0, "description": ""}

# Iterate though SAP['Description']
for job in SAP['Description']:
  highest_score = {"score": 0, "description": ""} # Reset highest_score at each iteration
  for description in SAPH['Description']: # Iterate through SAPH['Description']
    similarity_score = similar(job, description) # Get their similarity

    if(similarity_score > highest_score['score']): # Check if the similarity is higher than the already saved similarity. If so, update highest_score with the new values
      highest_score['score'] = similarity_score
      highest_score['description'] = description
    if(similarity_score == 100): # If it's a perfect match, don't bother continuing to search.
      break
  # Update the dataframe 'scores' with highest_score
  scores['SAPH'][scores['SAP'] == job] = highest_score['description'] 
  scores['Similarity'][scores['SAP'] == job] = highest_score['score']
```

Here's a breakdown:

1. A temporary variable, `highest_score` is created to store, well, the highest computed scores.
2. Now we iterate thorough `SAP['Description']`, and within, iterate though `SAPH['Description']`. This allows us to compare each value of `SAP['Description']` (`job`) to every value of `SAPH['Description']` (`description`).
3. While iterating though `SAPH['Description']`, we:

   1. Compute the similarity score of both `job` and `description`
   2. If it's higher than the saved score in `highest_score`, we update `highest_score` accordingly; otherwise we continue
   3. If `similarity_score` is equal to `100`, we know that it's a perfect match, and don't have to keep looking. We break the loop in this case.
4. Outside of the `SAPH['Description']` loop, now that we've compared `job` to each element of `SAPH['Description']`, (or found a perfect match), we save the values to `scores`.

This repeats for every element of `SAP['Description']`.

Here's what `scores` looks like when it's finished:

```
                                        SAP                                      SAPH Similarity
0  Detailed Inspection of Masts (2100mm) (3  Detailed Inspection of Masts (2100mm) (3        100
1   Ceremonial Awnings-Survey and Load Test   Ceremonial Awnings-Survey and Load Test        100
2   HPA-Carry out 4000 hour service routine   HPA-Carry out 8000 hour service routine    94.7368
3   UxE 8 in Number Temperature Probs for C   UxE 8 in Number Temperature Probs for C        100
4                           Overhaul valves                         Represerve valves    53.4522
```

And after outputting it to a CSV file with this:

```py
# Output it to Scores.csv without the index column (0, 1, 2, 3... far left in scores above). Remove index=False if you want to keep the index column.
scores.to_csv('Scores.csv', index=False)
```

...**Scores.csv** looks like this:

```
SAP,SAPH,Similarity
Detailed Inspection of Masts (2100mm) (3,Detailed Inspection of Masts (2100mm) (3,100
Ceremonial Awnings-Survey and Load Test,Ceremonial Awnings-Survey and Load Test,100
HPA-Carry out 4000 hour service routine,HPA-Carry out 8000 hour service routine,94.73684210526315
UxE 8 in Number Temperature Probs for C,UxE 8 in Number Temperature Probs for C,100
Overhaul valves,Represerve valves,53.45224838248488
```

[View the full code, and run and edit it online](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/JubilantExcitableApplicationserver-1#main.py)

**Note that** `textdistance` **and** `pandas` **are required libraries for this. Install them, if you don't have them already, with:**

```
pip install textdistance pandas
```

---

**Notes:**

- You can round the percent by replacing `f'{highest_score}%'` with this: `f'{round(highest_score, NUMBER_OF_PLACES_TO_ROUND_TO)}%'`
- [Here's a formatted version](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/JubilantExcitableApplicationserver-3#Scores.csv), and [here's the code](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/JubilantExcitableApplicationserver-3#main.py)

---

**EDIT:** (for the problems encountered that are mentioned in the comments)

Here is an error-catching version of the similarity function:

```py
def similar(a, b): # adapted from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63838615/8402369
  try: 
    similarity = 1-textdistance.Cosine(qval=2).distance(a, b) 
    return similarity * 100
  except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('There was an error. Here are the values of a and b that were passed')
    print(f'a: {repr(a)}')
    print(f'b: {repr(b)}')
    exit()
```

Comment: Hi marsnebula, is there anyway to get the output CSV to be on two columns? Description and Similairty? Thanks

Comment: [The last link I provided](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/JubilantExcitableApplicationserver-3#main.py) does just that.

Comment: Do you want it to be separated by commas, not formatted? Because this returns a formatted version.

Comment: @Andy_Stillwell - Like [this](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/JubilantExcitableApplicationserver-4#Scores.csv)? [Code](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/JubilantExcitableApplicationserver-4#main.py)

Comment: Hi, when its exported to csv all the data is contained in column A. Is there any way for Column A to have the description and Column B to have the similarity score?

Comment: But there are two columns outputted by the code in the link above: Description and Similarity.

Comment: I know, however when I load up the csv file, the data is just on one string under column A

Comment: It *is* valid so there shouldn't be a problem

Comment: I am just loading the csv file up in excel and its all in column A. Is there another way how I should be reading it?

Comment: Let me try that. Give me a min

Comment: Looks [fine to me](https://i.gyazo.com/476251a95b36a28bb659b6163c163a25.png). Are you copying and pasting the data into excel? If you download the [CSV file](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/JubilantExcitableApplicationserver-4#Scores.csv), and open it with excel it seems to work fine.

Comment: The program creates a csv file? I am just loading it up and its all in column A?

Comment: Yes it creates a CSV file, but if you want an excel output, it can create an excel file instead, like [this](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/JubilantExcitableApplicationserver-5#main.py) although you will have to download it to view it.

Comment: Hi @marsnebulasoup, its me again. Finally got access through the work firewall and downloaded textdistance into python. It worked fine on a 2,300 row data set, however I have just tried to put 13,000 rows through it and an error has come up.

Comment: File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textdistance\algorithms\base.py", line 176, in similarity

    return self(*sequences)

 

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textdistance\algorithms\token_based.py", line 175, in __call__

    return intersection / pow(prod, 1.0 / len(sequences))

 

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Comment: If it works fine for one set of CSV files, but not the other, it'd seem like the problem is in the CSVs' content. Perhaps there are some empty rows or something in the CSV data that is screwing the similarity comparison up...are you able to share the CSV files?

Comment: Also, maybe it could be a formatting issue. Both SAP and SAPH need to have one column with the header 'Description' for pandas to read it properly. One more thing...it doesn't seem like what you've posted is the full stack trace; it doesn't say on what line *in your program* does this fail. Can you edit the question to include the full message or send a link to a pastebin or something? Comments are limited to 500 or so characters, I believe, so there might not be enough room for the full message in a comment.

Comment: Hi, I have included the full error trace on the original post. I cannot get the csv files out but both are formatted the same way. Notification and Description being the headers.

Comment: So I am thinking that this could be a problem with the headers. If you change the `Notification` header in the CSV file to `Description`, does it work? That probably isn't the problem, though, because it would most likely throw a KeyError, not a ZeroDivisionError. You need to find out what is being passed to the similarity function that raises this error. I've edited the above answer that I posted to include a similarity function with error catching. If you replace your similarity function with that one, you can see what is being passed to the function that throws the error...

Comment: ...i.e, what from the CSV file is messing the code up. Alternatively, I would think that a solution would be to make sure the values passed to `textdistance` are strings, so you can replace this part of your similarity function: `.distance(a, b)` with `.distance(str(a), str(b))`

Comment: Hi, that error check has worked thankyou very much. There were two rows that had 3 and . as the description which it kept falling down on. It took my work computer around 5 hours to do a 17k vs 22k row comparison. On receipt of that I think I need two more bits of info if you can help? On the Scores file I need the Notification number to sit alongside the Description and if I am intepretating how it works correctly when it goes through the descriptions contained in SAPH it must go through the entire list and then select the one with the highest %? Could it also return in the scores sheet that

Comment: notification number? 

So on ther scores workbook there would be 4 columns. 

Notification (SAP), Description (SAP), Similarity (Calc), Notification (SAPH)

Does that make sense?

Thanks Andrew

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by notification number. Do you mean the indexes (line numbers) of the lines compared? Eg. So if line 3 in SAP and line 5 in SAPH were a match, it would look like this in Scores.csv: `3, Line from SAP, 98%, 5` Is this what you are looking for? If not could you possibly edit your question to include an an example of your desired output - just a few lines of Scores.csv, and explain what each column is supposed to be?

Comment: Have ammended the original post. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: @AndyStillwell - Something like [this](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/JubilantExcitableApplicationserver-7#Scores.csv)? Here's the [code](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/JubilantExcitableApplicationserver-7#main.py). It honestly took way longer than I expected but anyways...it should work for you, although I don't know how you want the output to be formatted.

Comment: Hi, it comes up with an error. I have put the trace in under edit 3 above

Comment: Okay, this is probably something to do with SAP.csv and SAPH.csv. Are they formatted like SAP.csv and SAPH.csv in the code I linked in the comment above? If not can you provide a sample of the first bit of the file so I can see where it differs from what I have in the code?

Comment: The notification numbers are just in as a General format on the .csv files

Comment: What do you mean by "general format"? I don't understand that. What I'm trying do is tell if SAP.csv and SAPH.csv have to exact same structure as SAP.csv and SAPH.csv in [the repl.it link in my comment above](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/JubilantExcitableApplicationserver-7#main.py). If they have a different structure, then the code will fail, so can you edit your post to include like the first 10 or so lines of SAP.csv and SAPH.csv so I can change the code accordingly? Otherwise I'm just guessing how it looks like.

Comment: Hi, I think I have updated the original post to include notifcations but when I post it into excel it doesnt fill two columns.

Comment: It seems like each value of SAP and SAPH are separated by six spaces, so I changed the delimiter from the default (comma) to that. However, the headers in SAP and SAPH seem to be separated by three spaces only, so I copied the six whitespaces from a line below, and replaced those three spaces with the six, so all the fields are delimited identically. Alternatively, you could do a find and replace and replace those six spaces with commas, and it should work with the code you already have. But here is the modified code (and CSV files) that work:

Comment: https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/JubilantExcitableApplicationserver-7#SAP.csv

Comment: So, as I understand it, it runs fine on repl.it but not locally? Is it possible that you didn't copy the code correctly from repl.it to your computer, so that's why it's not working? I don't see why it can't work locally but works online...there's probably some differences between the code online and local. Other than that, you can try changing `dtype={'Notification':'string'}` in SAP and SAPH to `dtype={'Notification':'object'}`, but I'm not sure if that'll make a difference.

Comment: Also when you edit your post, you can format code by surrounding it with triple backticks (```), or highlighting it, then hitting Ctrl-K or Command-K depending on your OS

Comment: Hi, have spent a few hours trying to solve it but no luck.

Could you try having two csv files with the data and trying to run it? I am still getting the d type error

Comment: Okay I have tried it [with the space-delimited CSV files](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/JubilantExcitableApplicationserver-7#main.py)  and [the comma-delimited ones](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/JubilantExcitableApplicationserver-8#main.py), and they work each time. Since we are using the same code, the only reason it can't be working is that there's something in the CSV files that is screwing things up. Perhaps it has something to do with that line that threw the ZeroDivisionError? Did you remove that line? I don't know how much I can actually help without seeing the CSV files...

Comment: ...but I can write a function that will check if the delimiter changes throughout the CSV files, because that could be a reason it's not working.