# Pandas: How to avoid duplicated value when the value is an url?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in my dataframe for articles that looks like this:

```
id link
1  https://www.msn.com/rachat-de-soufflet-par-invivo-les-secrets-dun-deal-%C3%A0-2-milliards-deuros/ar-BB1cKCRg
2  https://www.msn.com/rachat-de-soufflet-par-invivo-les-secrets-d-un-deal-%C3%A0-2-milliards-deuros/ar-BB1cKCRg
3  other link
```

For example the two first urls look to be the same but change here:

> d-un-deal

In my dataframe I have some links that are almost similar. The content is the same but the link change, sometimes the difference between the two links is a letter having an uppercase in one of the link or just other character differing.

Example:

```
url1 = https://site/presidency...
url2 = https://site/Presidency...

url3 = https://site/news-of-today
```

`url4 = same as url3 but at the end` `?autoplay`

How can I check all the links and delete the duplicates (similar content but the link is changing a little) ?

Comment: create a function to detect duplicate rows then use `apply()` to filter the rows

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that sometimes they are not real duplicates. Because the value of url change in just one character for example

Comment: For the upper/lowercase you can default all the text to lower and delete duplicates, for the other cases I don't really know

Comment: you can add different cases in the function

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

[Find the similarity metric between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388213/find-the-similarity-metric-between-two-strings)

You could use a metric for this. Decide which similarity you want to use.

Comment: I don 't think this will work. Having a close similarity doesn't assure that the link has the same or different content.

Comment: You can't avoid this problem, but he could never do a function with all cases, cause the cases could change (and every case [like another number at the end] don't implies it is the same content).

Comment: OP could try and send a request and compare the results

Comment: You should write an answer and not comments. If you have a solution reply to OP! I just wrote it would be ONE solution, not the one and only...