# Similarity score to filter dataframe columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nlp, data-cleaning, rex

I have a pandas dataframe, `df` with the following column names

```
columns = ['Baillie Gifford Positive Change Fund B Accumulation',
 'Stewart Investors Worldwide Select Fund Class B (accumulation) Gbp',
 'Stewart Investors Worldwide Select Fund Class A (accumulation) Gbp',
 'Close Ftse Techmark Fund X Acc',
 'Stewart Investors Asia Pacific Leaders Fund Class B (accumulation) Gbp',
 'Stewart Investors Asia Pacific Leaders Fund Class A (accumulation) Gbp',
 'Stewart Investors Worldwide Sustainability Fund Class A (accumulation) Gbp',
 'Stewart Investors Worldwide Sustainability Fund Class B (accumulation) Gbp',
 'Mi Somerset Emerging Markets Dividend Growth A Accumulation Shares',
 'Axa Framlington Biotech Fund Gbp Z Acc',
 'Stewart Investors Global Emerging Markets Sustainability Fund Class B (accumulation) Gbp',
 'Schroder Asian Income Fund L Accumulation Gbp',
 'Fidelity Active Strategy - Fast - Asia Fund Y-acc-gbp',
 'Lf Miton Uk Value Opportunities Fund B Institutional Accumulation',
 'Liontrust India Fund C Acc Gbp',
 'Fidelity Asian Dividend Fund W Acc',
 'Stewart Investors Global Emerging Markets Sustainability Fund Class A (accumulation) Gbp',
 'Quilter Investors Emerging Markets Equity Growth Fund U2 (gbp) Accumulation',
 'Man Glg Continental European Growth Fund Retail Accumulation Shares (class A)',
 'Quilter Investors Europe (ex Uk) Equity Growth Fund A (gbp) Accumulation']
```

What I want is to filter columns that are similar and keep one of them.

For example, `'Stewart Investors Worldwide Select Fund Class B (accumulation) Gbp'`, is similar to identical to `'Stewart Investors Worldwide Select Fund Class A (accumulation) Gbp'`,

I was thinking that some of the similarity scores used in NLP to identify similar text might help here. But I do not know how to apply in my case.

The expected outcome should be a list (which I will use to filter my dataframe) that keeps one of the similar texts. For example:

```
columns_filtered = ['Baillie Gifford Positive Change Fund B Accumulation',
 'Stewart Investors Worldwide Select Fund Class B (accumulation) Gbp',
 'Close Ftse Techmark Fund X Acc',
 'Stewart Investors Asia Pacific Leaders Fund Class A (accumulation) Gbp',
 'Stewart Investors Worldwide Sustainability Fund Class B (accumulation) Gbp',
 'Mi Somerset Emerging Markets Dividend Growth A Accumulation Shares',
 'Axa Framlington Biotech Fund Gbp Z Acc',
 'Stewart Investors Global Emerging Markets Sustainability Fund Class B (accumulation) Gbp',
 'Schroder Asian Income Fund L Accumulation Gbp',
 'Fidelity Active Strategy - Fast - Asia Fund Y-acc-gbp',
 'Lf Miton Uk Value Opportunities Fund B Institutional Accumulation',
 'Liontrust India Fund C Acc Gbp',
 'Fidelity Asian Dividend Fund W Acc',
 'Stewart Investors Global Emerging Markets Sustainability Fund Class A (accumulation) Gbp',
 'Quilter Investors Emerging Markets Equity Growth Fund U2 (gbp) Accumulation',
 'Man Glg Continental European Growth Fund Retail Accumulation Shares (class A)',
 'Quilter Investors Europe (ex Uk) Equity Growth Fund A (gbp) Accumulation']
```

Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the similarity metric between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388213/find-the-similarity-metric-between-two-strings)

Comment: if I have 10 columns, checking each pair means that should check 10*10 different combinations to check. So, how I can implement this then when the actual number of columns is 100? Is there any scalable solution?

Comment: hack solution: you can try sorting `columns` and then check similarity between neighbors. It would give you O(n*log(n) + n) => O(n*log(n)),  instead of O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity 
import numpy as np


vectorizer = CountVectorizer().fit_transform(df.columns.tolist())
vector = vectorizer.toarray()

similarity_score = cosine_similarity(vector)


df_similarity = pd.DataFrame(np.asmatrix(similarity_score))
df_similarity.columns = df.columns
df_similarity.index = df.columns
df_similarity
```

The `df_similarity` is a dataframe where it holds the similarity index of each column name against other columns names.

Note that I used one of the similarity scores used in NLP. One can use any similarity score might like.