# Cosine similarity between multiple text columns of dataframe and list of names

Tags: python, pandas, cosine-similarity, tfidfvectorizer, textmatching

HI I am looking calculate cosine similarity between multiple text columns of a dataframe with a list of name to return a best match and similarity score. Also looking to return true false based on score based on similarity threshold.

Example Data looks like below,

#df1

```
name1         name2      name 3
mahesh        suresh     suvarna
suresh        suresh     gv rao
suvarna       gv rao     ravi
kumar varma   Varma      suvarna
ravi shankar  robert     peter
d man mohan   kumar      man mohan
```

#df2 or Name List

```
white_list
suresh
ram
rao gv
kumar varma
sameer
d mohan
```

#Expected output

```
Best_match  Score   result
Mahesh      0.85    TRUE
Ravi Kumar  0.32    FALSE
Suresh      0.48    FALSE
Varma       0.52    FALSE
Sameer      0.32    FALSE
Mohan       0.81    TRUE
```

Can someone please help me to do this.

Comment: try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68718205/8664422)

Comment: Tried but not working as I am looking to get similarity between each element in multiple columns of df with an entire list and return best match out of these columns with the list on corresponding row wise

Comment: you can pick all elements to single array, then apply cs and sort,  `sum(df.apply(lambda x: list(set(x))), [])` would give single list of all elements