# Comparing similarities in two lists of complex words

Tags: python, python-3.x, similarity

I have thousands of items within `check_word_list`.

I want to replace the items in `check_word_list` with items in `correct_product_name_list` in the order of `check_word_list`, so that the result will be exactly like the `result_list`.

The word of each corresponding item will have similarities (for e.g. `correct_product_name_list[4]` is similar to `check_word_list[2]`), they are both the same item, but has different naming, so I want to name it according to `correct_product_name_list`, so that the result will be like the `result_list`. How do I do that?

```
correct_product_name_list = [
'DANCOW FORTIGRO INSTANT COKLAT SUSU BUBUK 40GR',
'DANCOW FORTIGRO SACHET INSTAN SUSU BUBUK (10 X 27 GR)',
'HAVERJOY ROLLED OATS 1 KG - DUS',    
'KONDOM SUTRA CLASSIC ISI 24 PCS', 
'KONDOM SUTRA OK ISI 12 PCS', 
'TISSUE BASAH DETOL WET WIPES ISI 50 LEMBAR' 
'VASELINE HYPOALLERGENIC REPAIRING JELLY BABY 50ML', 
]

check_word_list = [
'DANCOW FORTIGRO SACHET INSTAN SUSU BUBUK (10 X 27 GR) - Coklat, 5 pcs',
'KONDOM SUTRA CLASSIC ISI 1 3 12 24 SUTERA MERAH not durex / fiesta - 3pcs', 
'HAVERJOY HAVERMOUT ROLLED OATS 1 KG - KUNING',  
'DANCOW FORTIGRO SACHET INSTAN SUSU BUBUK (10 X 27 GR) - Vanila, 5 pcs', 
'TISU BASAH / TISSUE BASAH DETOL WET WIPES ISI 50 LEMBAR',  
'VASELINE HYPOALLERGENIC REPAIRING JELLY BABY 50 ML', 
'Kondom Sutra Ok isi 1 / 3 / 12 / 24 bukan durex / fiesta - 12pcs']

result_list = [
'DANCOW FORTIGRO INSTANT COKLAT SUSU BUBUK 40GR',  
'KONDOM SUTRA CLASSIC ISI 24 PCS', 
'HAVERJOY ROLLED OATS 1 KG - DUS', 
'DANCOW FORTIGRO SACHET INSTAN SUSU BUBUK (10 X 27 GR)', 
'TISSUE BASAH DETOL WET WIPES ISI 50 LEMBAR',
'VASELINE HYPOALLERGENIC REPAIRING JELLY BABY 50ML', 
'KONDOM SUTRA OK ISI 12 PCS']
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: I have no idea what to do to find similarities between the lists and make a new one. I read this article and it is likely something that I would like to achieve, but it is so hard to understand: https://towardsdatascience.com/calculating-string-similarity-in-python-276e18a7d33a. Is it possible to solve this without using keyword? Maybe, if both items in different list have the max matching word, then  the item on the correct_product_name_list will be copied and pasted onto the result list. I really have no idea if it is possible to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try what is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17388505/2844093), basically:

1. looping on `check_word_list`
2. looping on `correct_word_list`
3. compare the similarity off both words with `difflib`

Pseudocode:

```py
import difflib
result_list = []

# edit this to match your requirements
match_thresold = 0.5

for check_word in check_word_list:
    for correct_word in correct_word_list:
        if difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, check_word, correct_mord).ratio() >= match_threshold:
            result_list.append(correct_word)
```

Note: there are other libraries suggested in the linked answer if this one works for you!

Comment: If you know the order, and it's just a fill down exercise, you can use Excel for this. If you want to find similarities between strings, you can use fuzzy matching. Check out the link below and see if it helps your cause. https://towardsdatascience.com/fuzzy-string-matching-in-python-68f240d910fe

Comment: I have tried the difflib.SquenceMatcher, but it can't deliver precise result. But thank you, I will try other methods you suggest