# Find The Best Match In List of string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have

```
target = "dexter.new.blood.S01EP07.somerandomstring.mkv"
```

I managed to get only the name using `split('.')`
to be

```
target = "dexternewblood"
```

and

```py
list = ['Dexter - Eighth Season (2013)', 'Dexter - Seventh Season  (2012)', 'Dexter - Fourth Season (2009)', 'Dexter - Third Season (2008)', 'Dexter - Sixth Season (2011)', 'Dexter - Fifth Season (2010)', 'Dexter: New Blood - First Season (2021)', 'Dexter - First Season (2006)', 'Dexter - Second Season (2007)']
```

I did the same thing to end up with:

```py
list = ['Dexter ', 'Dexter ', 'Dexter ', 'Dexter ', 'Dexter ', 'Dexter ', 'Dexter: New Blood ', 'Dexter ', 'Dexter ']
```

I wanna get the best match which is "Dexter: New Blood"
if you can add way for getting index as well

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you rigorously define what you mean by "best match"? What have you tried so far, and what isn't working about what you have tried?

Comment: "I wanna get the best match which is "Dexter: New Blood"" **Why** is this the best match? What is the rule that tells you so? If I say that the best match is instead "Dexter ", why am I wrong?

Comment: @Khalid-elhirche As others have said, you have to say **exactly** what you mean by "best match" (i.e. a rule for saying whether one match is better than the other) for us to be able to help you. For example, perhaps you could use the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to say how good a match is.

Comment: i want based on the target like what's the close match to target

Comment: @Khalid-elhirche What does "close" mean?

Comment: @Khalid-elhirche How exactly would a computer be able to figure out that "Dexter: New Blood" is "closer" than just "Dexter"?

Comment: target = "dexternewblood" and my goal is to get "Dexter: New Blood",bcuz it's more close to target ,sorry idk how to explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388213/find-the-similarity-metric-between-two-strings) you can use [`SequenceMatcher`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-objects) from [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) built-in  module:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

target = "dexternewblood"
lst = ['Dexter ', 'Dexter ', 'Dexter ', 'Dexter ', 'Dexter ', 'Dexter ', 'Dexter: New Blood ', 'Dexter ', 'Dexter ']

a = [SequenceMatcher(None, i, target).ratio() for i in lst]

index = a.index(max(a)) # 6
match = lst[index] # 'Dexter: New Blood '
```