# Search System for tables

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming

I'm trying to make a search function, but I'm not sure how I should implement this. I want the function to take the input string and find the string that is closest to the input and return it.

**Table:**

```json
 {
    "Death": { "Value": 190000, "Demand": 4, "Trend": 1, "Tier": "S" },
    "Legendary Borul (Alternative)": { "Value": 125000, "Demand": 2, "Trend": 1, "Tier": "S" },
    "Club Beast": { "Value": 50000, "Demand": 6, "Trend": 1, "Tier": "S" },
    "Dark Wing": { "Value": 19800, "Demand": 6, "Trend": 1, "Tier": "S" },
    "Zaruto (GRR III)": { "Value": 18800, "Demand": 6, "Trend": 1, "Tier": "S" },
    "First Wood Bender": { "Value": 17000, "Demand": 8, "Trend": 1, "Tier": "S" },
    "Old Will": { "Value": 14500, "Demand": 5, "Trend": 1, "Tier": "S" },
    "Martial Artist": { "Value": 12000, "Demand": 3, "Trend": 6, "Tier": "S" },
    "Expert Sorcerer": { "Value": 11250, "Demand": 5, "Trend": 1, "Tier": "S" },
    "Zaruto (GRR II)": { "Value": 9600, "Demand": 8, "Trend": 7, "Tier": "S" },
    "Sandwhich Leader / Mecha Frieza": { "Value": 1050000, "Demand": 0, "Trend": 4, "Tier": "S" },
    "First Wood Bender (Sage)": { "Value": "N/A", "Demand": 0, "Trend": 4, "Tier": "S" }
}
```

Example:

```js
search("legen"); // --> Output: 
    "Legendary Borul (Alternative)": { "Value": 125000, "Demand": 2, "Trend": 1, "Tier": "S" },
```

Comment: looks like you simply want to check if a sub-string occurs or not in your search table

Answer (score 0):

Well your question is a bit vague, you have not cleared what type of match you want so for example from your example it looks a simple sub string match just in case you can try following way to search in your table

**Method 1 (Simple)**

```
import json

table = {
    "Death": {"Value": 190000, "Demand": 4, "Trend": 1, "Tier": "S"},
    "Legendary Borul (Alternative)": {"Value": 125000, "Demand": 2, "Trend": 1, "Tier": "S"},
    "Club Beast": {"Value": 50000, "Demand": 6, "Trend": 1, "Tier": "S"},
    "Dark Wing": {"Value": 19800, "Demand": 6, "Trend": 1, "Tier": "S"},
    "Zaruto (GRR III)": {"Value": 18800, "Demand": 6, "Trend": 1, "Tier": "S"},
    "First Wood Bender": {"Value": 17000, "Demand": 8, "Trend": 1, "Tier": "S"},
    "Old Will": {"Value": 14500, "Demand": 5, "Trend": 1, "Tier": "S"},
    "Martial Artist": {"Value": 12000, "Demand": 3, "Trend": 6, "Tier": "S"},
    "Expert Sorcerer": {"Value": 11250, "Demand": 5, "Trend": 1, "Tier": "S"},
    "Zaruto (GRR II)": {"Value": 9600, "Demand": 8, "Trend": 7, "Tier": "S"},
    "Sandwhich Leader / Mecha Frieza": {"Value": 1050000, "Demand": 0, "Trend": 4, "Tier": "S"},
    "First Wood Bender (Sage)": {"Value": "N/A", "Demand": 0, "Trend": 4, "Tier": "S"}
}


def Search(q):
    q = q.lower()
    for key in table.keys():
        if q in key.lower():
            return key + ": " + json.dumps(table[key])
    return False


print(Search('legen'))
```

Output:

> Legendary Borul (Alternative): {"Value": 125000, "Demand": 2, "Trend":
> 1, "Tier": "S"}

Other Methods

You can try to search using semantics of the string for example test and best have same semantics, hence greater similarity index

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388213/find-the-similarity-metric-between-two-strings) stack post highlights such methods e.g. hamming distance between two strings or smoothing functions for searching