# How to make DeepDiff output human readable?

Tags: python, c++, deep-diff

DeepDiff results look like:

```
{'dictionary_item_added': [root[5], root[6]], 'dictionary_item_removed': [root[4]]}
```

For human review of changes, this only works for small examples. I need something like the code file differences displayed in GitHub commits and pull requests but for json.

So here is my question:

How to convert DeepDiff output to something like [image: human readable diff]?

### Why I don't want to drop DeepDiff and use git-diff

Unlike in code, json does not care about format and json doesn't care about order of keys in dictionaries.

I could get around not using DeepDiff by pre-sorting all dictionaries in json and then comparing them with git-diff. Yet writing files to disk and shelling out to `git-diff` is messy. Just doing `DeepDiff(t1, t2)` is very clean.

The example I'm looking at is:

```python
from deepdiff import DeepDiff
t1 = {1:1, 3:3, 4:4}
t2 = {1:1, 3:3, 5:5, 6:6}
ddiff = DeepDiff(t1, t2)
print(ddiff)
```

## Specifics that I'm looking for

I'd like to see words highlighted within values that got changed, like so:

[image: diff with words highlighted]
With a few differences:

- This is an example of code but it works for json just as well
- I only need this for text-based terminals that support ANSI colors
- I'm looking on how to do this in Python or C++
- The GitHub screenshot has the idea that I like: show lines with - / + and highlight words within each line

Comment: Can you tell us what you have already tried to achieve this? We won't be able to help you without knowing your existing code.

Comment: This [gist](https://gist.github.com/ines/04b47597eb9d011ade5e77a068389521) may be able to help.

Comment: Also, this may be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500167/how-to-show-diff-of-two-string-sequences-in-colors) (which also may be where the gist originated from)

Comment: I believe this is more of a freelance project than a Stack Overflow question with a bounty.

Comment: I ran the DeepDiff example and this:
`echo -e '{\n  "1": 1,\n  "3": 3,\n  "4": 4\n}' > /tmp/left; echo -e '{\n  "1": 1,\n  "3": 3,\n  "5": 5\n  "6": 6\n}' > /tmp/right; git diff /tmp/left /tmp/right; git diff --color-words=. /tmp/left /tmp/right` yet here I don't like how git-diff displays word differences. The GitHub screenshot has the best idea: show lines with - / + and highlight words within each line.

Comment: @LeoDog896 unlike that question I'm looking to show lines with - / + and highlight words within each line

Answer (score 7):

[difflib's ndiff](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.ndiff) may be what you're trying to accomplish:

```py
import difflib
import json
from typing import Callable

t1 = {1:1, 3:3, 4:4}
t2 = {1:1, 3:3, 5:5, 6:6}

RED: Callable[[str], str] = lambda text: f"\u001b[31m{text}\033\u001b[0m"
GREEN: Callable[[str], str] = lambda text: f"\u001b[32m{text}\033\u001b[0m"

def get_edits_string(old: str, new: str) -> str:
    result = ""

    lines = difflib.ndiff(old.splitlines(keepends=True), new.splitlines(keepends=True))
    
    for line in lines:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line.startswith("+"):
            result += GREEN(line) + "\n"
        elif line.startswith("-"):
            result += RED(line) + "\n"
        elif line.startswith("?"):
            continue
        else:
            result += line + "\n"

    return result

print(
    get_edits_string(
        json.dumps(t1, indent=4, sort_keys=True),
        json.dumps(t2, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    )
)
```

[image]

The benefit for this can also be helpful in the case of CLIs -- I've filtered it in the code, but it also has color-less diffs with a `?` marking where the changes are.

Comment: It's important to add `sort_keys=True` to json.dumps to not be susceptible to random ordering of keys. This is great and the core of what I needed, Thank you! It would be even more helpful if for larger strings within json if word differences are highlighted. It's like a diff within a diff :)

Comment: Thanks for the revision! It'd be extra user friendly if the diff truncates long runs of unmodified json. Similar to how GitHub, git diff, and hg diff do it. Rational: for large json where only a few places get edited it's time consuming for a human to scroll thru all of it to review each modification.

Comment: oh that was easy, just had to replace `ndiff` with `unified_diff(a, b, fromfile="before", tofile="after")`

Comment: Were you able to achieve what you were looking for?

Comment: `lines = ''.join(lines)` followed by `lines.splitlines()` this seems strange and sometimes a line will not have a "\n" at the end so this will end up fusing lines. Did you mean to use `.rstrip()` instead?

Comment: also the codes don't reset boldness, i found this to work instead: `RED: Callable[[str], str] = lambda text: f"\u001b[31m{text}\033\u001b[0m"` and `32m` for green

Comment: When lines start with "?" why skip them?

Comment: They didn't fit with the idea you had -- but I would remove them personally since they're better for CLI output.

Comment: oh i see, `unified_diff` does not print "?"'s - i switched to `unified_diff` (rational in my Nov 9 comment)