# Marking dynamic substrings in a list of strings

Tags: python, algorithm

Assume these two sets of strings:

```
file=sheet-2016-12-08.xlsx
file=sheet-2016-11-21.xlsx
file=sheet-2016-11-12.xlsx
file=sheet-2016-11-08.xlsx
file=sheet-2016-10-22.xlsx
file=sheet-2016-09-29.xlsx
file=sheet-2016-09-05.xlsx
file=sheet-2016-09-04.xlsx

size=1024KB
size=22KB
size=980KB
size=15019KB
size=202KB
```

I need to run a function on both these sets separately and receive the following output respectively:

```
file=sheet-2016-*.xlsx

size=*KB
```

The dataset can be any set of strings. It doesn't have to match the format. Here's another example for instance:

```
id.4030.paid
id.1280.paid
id.88.paid
```

For which the expected output would be:

```
id.*.paid
```

Basically, I need a function to analyze a set of strings and replace the uncommon substring with an asterisk(*)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could use `os.path.commonprefix` to compute the common prefix. It is used to compute shared directories in a list of filepaths, but it can be used in a generic context.

Then reverse the strings, and apply common prefix again, then reverse, to compute common suffix (adapted from https://gist.github.com/willwest/ca5d050fdf15232a9e67)

```
dataset = """id.4030.paid
id.1280.paid
id.88.paid""".splitlines()

import os


# Return the longest common suffix in a list of strings
def longest_common_suffix(list_of_strings):
    reversed_strings = [s[::-1] for s in list_of_strings]
    return os.path.commonprefix(reversed_strings)[::-1]

common_prefix = os.path.commonprefix(dataset)
common_suffix = longest_common_suffix(dataset)

print("{}*{}".format(common_prefix,common_suffix))
```

result:

```
id.*.paid
```

EDIT: as wim noted:

- when all strings are equal, common prefixes & suffixes are the same, but it should return the string itself instead of `prefix*suffix`: should check if all strings are the same
- when common prefix & suffixes overlap/have shared letters, this confuses the computation as well: should compute common suffix on the string minus the common prefix

So a all-in-one method is required to test the list beforehand to make sure that at least 2 strings are different (condensing the prefix/suffix formula in the process), and compute common suffix with slicing to remove common prefix:

```
def compute_generic_string(dataset):
    # edge case where all strings are the same
    if len(set(dataset))==1:
        return dataset[0]

    commonprefix = os.path.commonprefix(dataset)

    return "{}*{}".format(commonprefix,os.path.commonprefix([s[len(commonprefix):][::-1] for s in dataset])[::-1])
```

now let's test this:

```
for dataset in [['id.4030.paid','id.1280.paid','id.88.paid'],['aBBc', 'aBc'],[]]:
    print(compute_generic_string(dataset))
```

result:

```
id.*.paid
aB*c
*
```

(when dataset is empty, code returns `*`, maybe that should be another edge case)

Comment: Dang, `os.path.commonprefix`!  How long has that been around.

Comment: pretty nice one, plus one

Comment: @wim nice catch. Tough to spot, easy to fix

Comment: os.path.commonprefix is not very difficult to implement, but a bit tedious. So it's great that it's built-in.

Comment: This still has bugs.  For example, input `['aBBc', 'aBc']` returns `'aB*Bc'` due to overlap of the common prefix and suffix.

Comment: @wim: right! tough to spot and tough to fix. reverse wildcard isn't that easy. I take on the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

```
from os.path import commonprefix

def commonsuffix(m):
    return commonprefix([s[::-1] for s in m])[::-1]

def inverse_glob(strs):
    start = commonprefix(strs)
    n = len(start)
    ends = [s[n:] for s in strs]
    end = commonsuffix(ends)
    if start and not any(ends):
        return start
    else:
        return start + '*' + end
```

This problem is trickier than it seems at face value.

As currently specified, the question remains poorly constrained, i.e. there is not a unique solution.  For input `['spamAndEggs', 'spamAndHamAndEggs']`, both `spam*AndEggs` and `spamAnd*Eggs` are valid answers.  For input `['aXXXXz', 'aXXXz']` there are *four* possible solutions.  In the code given above, we prefer choosing the longest possible prefix in order to make the solution unique.

Credit to [JFF's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45890218/674039) for pointing out the existence of [`os.path.commonprefix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonprefix).

[Inverse glob - reverse engineer a wildcard string from file names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43808808/674039) is a related and more difficult generalisation of this question.

Comment: thanks for your comments & help to make my solution better. Some may object that your solution is a copy of mine, but without your comments, I couldn't have achieved a working one.

Comment: FWIW my [original solution](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45890262/1) had same bug as yours.   Deleted it when I saw your implementation, that was better.

Comment: we can say we beat that one together :)