# How would I detect duplicate elements of a string from another string in python?

Tags: python, string, list, duplicates, detection

So how would I go about finding a duplicate element of a string from another string in python using a for the most part one-to-two line or a quick fix?

for example,

```
str1 = "abccde"
str2 = "abcde"
# gets me c
```

Through the use of str2, finding there was a duplicate element in str1, so detecting that str1 has a duplicate of an element in str2. Not sure if there's a way through .count to do that, like str1.count(str2) or something.

I'm using this contextually for my hangman assignment and I'm a beginner coder, so we are using mostly built-in functions and the basics for the assignments, and there's a piece of my code within my loop that will keep printing because it dings the double letters.

Ex. hello, grinding, concoction.

So I pretty much made a "used" string, and I am trying to compare that to my correct letters list, and the guesses are 'appended' so I can avoid that.

note: they will be inputted, so I won't be able to say or just hardcode the letter c if that makes sense.

Thank you!

Comment: What happens if `str2` contains more dups like `abccccde` or letters do not exist in `str1` like `abcdez`?

Comment: Maybe you should consider a list or set instead of a string to keep track of guesses. It will make your task much easier!

Comment: `if "c" in "abccde": print('detected "c",)`

Comment: @PartialOrder how would I go about it if i wanted to do it in just lists?

Comment: @Chris detector will pretty much only care if str 1 has any duplicates of any char element in str 2 so `str1 = "abcdeffghi"   str2 = "aaaaaabbbbbbcccccddeeeeefffffggghhiii"` and str1 would ding me the letter f

Comment: When user inputs a letter in your hangman game, rather than appending to a string, you can append to list, e.g., `somelist.append(letter)`. Then if you only want letters guessed excluding duplicates you can use `set(somelist)`. Easier, right?

Answer (score 0):

You are basically searching a diff function between the two strings. Adapting [this beautiful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17904977/4092588)

```
import difflib

cases=[('abcccde', 'abcde')] 

for a,b in cases:     
    print('{} => {}'.format(a,b))  
    for i,s in enumerate(difflib.ndiff(a, b)):
        if s[0]==' ': continue
        elif s[0]=='-':
            print(u'The second string is missing the "{}" in position {} of the first string'.format(s[-1],i))
        elif s[0]=='+':
            print(u'The first string is missing the "{}" in position {} of the second string'.format(s[-1],i))    
    print()
```

Output

```
abcccde => abcde
The second string is missing the "c" in position 3 of the first string
The second string is missing the "c" in position 4 of the first string
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `set` with `str.count`:

```
def find_dup(str1, str2):
    return [i for i in set(str1) if str1.count(i) > 1 and i in set(str2)]
```

Output:

```
find_dup("abccde", "abcde")
# ['c']
find_dup("abcdeffghi" , "aaaaaabbbbbbcccccddeeeeefffffggghhiii") # from comment
# ['f']
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe you're trying to write a method similar to:

```
def duplicate_string(str1: str, str2: str) -> str:
    str2_set = set(str2)
    if len(str2_set) != len(str2):
        raise ValueError(f'{str2} has duplicate!')

    output = ''
    for char in str1:
        if char in str2_set:
            str2_set.remove(char)
        else:
            output += char

    return output


str1 = "abccccde"
str2 = "abcde"

print(duplicate_string(str1, str2))
```

#### Output

```
ccc
```

Here, we would first raise an error, if `str2` itself had a duplicate. Then, we'd loop through `str1`, either remove a char from the `str1_set` or append the duplicate in an `output` string.