# Finding the difference between two strings in python

Tags: python, string, set

Find the characters that occur in one string but not the other.

I have tried using the function `s1.difference(s2)` to get the difference in characters between two strings that are inputted from the user. However, when the program is run the computer returns `set()`. How can I get my code to return the different character(s)? 
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - difference between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904097/python-difference-between-two-strings)

Answer (score 3):

### Without duplicates

You can use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) to check the difference. Be aware that this solution does not consider the possibility of duplicate characters within a string:

```
In [2]: a = set('abcdef')
In [4]: b = set('ihgfed') 
In [5]: b.difference(a)  # all elements that are in `b` but not in `a`.
Out[5]: {'g', 'h', 'i'}

In [6]: b ^ a   # symmetric difference of `a` and `b` as a new set
Out[6]: {'a', 'b', 'c', 'g', 'h', 'i'}
```

If you want it to be a list:

```
In [7]: list(b.difference(a))                                                             
Out[7]: ['i', 'g', 'h']
```

---

### Check for multiple occurrences

You can also use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to treat the possibility of duplicate characters:

```
In [8]: import collections
In [9]: collections.Counter(a) - collections.Counter(b)                                   
Out[9]: Counter({'c': 1, 'a': 1, 'b': 1})
```

Or as a string:

```
In [15]: c = collections.Counter('abcccc') - collections.Counter('cbd')                   

In [16]: c                                                                                
Out[16]: Counter({'a': 1, 'c': 3})

In [17]: ''.join(c.elements())
Out[17]: 'accc'
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `sets` for that like this:

```py
a = 'abcd'
b = 'bcd'

diff = set(char for char in a) - set(char for char in b)
print(diff)

>>> {'a'}
```