# Is there a way to determine the indices where a python string differs from another string?

Tags: python, string, replace

I've searched far and wide and can't seem to find any prebuilt library that can do this:

Given 2 strings in python where one is the original string and the other has certain words replaced with place holders, I would like to identify the indices of the words in the original string that have been replaced with placeholders.

Example:

```
original = "This is the original string"

processed = "This is [placeholder] string"

indices = [8, 20]
```

The first index is the start of the substring that has been replaced, and the second index is the end of this substring.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/diff-match-patch-python/diff-match-patch

Comment: Take a look at the [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/difflib.html) module: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904097/python-difference-between-two-strings

Comment: i provided an answer, but just now i'm wondering, is it always the same placeholder? could you find the index of the `[` and `]` symbols?

Comment: @Nicolas Gervais no there could be more than one and they might be different

Comment: What other values for `[placeholder]` are there?

Answer (score 0):

That might not be the prettiest Python code I've written, but this would work:

```
first = [index for index, 
        (a, b) in enumerate(zip(list(original), 
        list(processed))) if a != b ][0]

second = [len(original) - index for index, 
         (a, b) in enumerate(zip(list(original[::-1]), 
         list(processed[::-1]))) if a != b ][0]

difference = [first, second]
```

It returns the first index where there is a discordance. And also the same backwards.

```
Out[76]: [8, 20]
```

In more detail:

1. Comparing every letter, it returns the first index where `first != second`
2. Comparing every letter starting from the end, it returns `len(first) - first difference`
3. It creates a list of these two indices

Comment: I forgot to mention there could be more than one placeholder in the text, in this case your solution won't do.