# How to identify common substrings of two strings in Python?

Tags: python, string, diff

How can I find common substrings of two strings in order to show changes/edit of a string?

So what I try to do is to compare an old version of a string:

```
string_old = "My name is pm730! How are you?"
```

with a new/edited version of the string:

```
string_new = "My name isn't pm730, it is pm740!"
```

Deleted substrings are not important. New substrings should be distinguished somehow, so that I could output it like this eventually:

> My name is**n't** pm730 **, it is pm740**!

This task sounds easy but is more complicated than I thought. So my hope is that there is already an similar implementation available, but unfortunanly I can't find it...

Comment: What you have tried by yourself so far?

Comment: Are you asking how you can *find* common substrings or how to display bold text?

Comment: @mkrieger1 How to find common substings  but bound on their location in order to eventually do somthing like the bold text. But the bold text isn't part of the question.

Comment: @ParthS007 I've already found all common substrings. I'm stuck on the part with the position bounding of the substrings.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904097/python-difference-between-two-strings?