# Compare requests with python

Tags: python, string, python-requests-html

I want to compare two requests (requests to website) with python. In the first step I'll get the response and save that in a variable (f1 and f2). After, I'll want to compare them and if there are difference, I want to know what's the difference. For example, difference can be a new button on the website or text changes of blog article.

```py
import requests

f1 = requests.get(link1)
f2 = requests.get(link2)

if f1.text == f2.text:
   #some code to analyse, what's the difference
   print('f1 and f2 is different')
```

How can get the difference between f1 and f2 in the best way?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "get the difference"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - difference between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904097/python-difference-between-two-strings)

Comment: Yes, I edit the post.

Comment: What do you think about this solution? => https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.HtmlDiff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the f1 and f2 by using .split(" ") and then use a for loop to get word for word differences in the two like so:

```
differentWords = {}
f1Split = f1.split(" ")
f2Split = f2.split(" ")
for i,b in f1Split,f2Split:
   if(f1Split[i] == f2Split[b]):
      #The words are the same
   else:
      differentWords.append(f"{f1Split}:{f2Split}")
```

The ideas are there but I think that this should hypothetically be a start to your solution.