# How do I compare two strings in python for differences?

Tags: python

I've got two strings like this:

```
string1 = "Foo Bar"
string2 = "Foo BBar"
```

How do I compare them to see the difference? If I just compare `string1[i]` to `string2[i]` I just end up with the last Word "Bar" being different, as, for example, `string1[5]` isn't the same as `string2[5]`, and so on.

Is there a way to just output "B"?

Comment: Take a look at [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @barmar, [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) may be the way to go here.

So here's a snippet just to fit your example, but it may not be suited for all your cases.

```
import difflib

string1 = "Foo Bar"
string2 = "Foo BBar"

[d[2:] for d in difflib.ndiff(string1, string2) if d.startswith("+")]
# ['B']
```

If you want to know more about it, please read the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17904977/5692012).