# Python - Highlight differences between two strings in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, string, jupyter-notebook, diff, highlight

I have a list of two strings, and I want to ***highlight*** and print differences between two strings (specifically in Jupyter notebook). By differences, I specifically mean the insertions, deletions and replacements needed to change one of the strings to the other.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17904097/7120031) which is similar but doesn't mention a way to present the changes.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out an effective way to display such highlighting and want to share it with others.

The `difflib` module gives you the tools to effectively find the differences, specifically the `SequenceMatcher` class, while the `IPython.display` module helps you highlight the differences in a notebook setting.

### Demonstration

First, let's assume the data in the following format:

```py
cases = [
    ('afrykanerskojęzyczny', 'afrykanerskojęzycznym'),    
    ('afrykanerskojęzyczni', 'nieafrykanerskojęzyczni'),
    ('afrykanerskojęzycznym', 'afrykanerskojęzyczny'),
    ('nieafrykanerskojęzyczni', 'afrykanerskojęzyczni'),
    ('nieafrynerskojęzyczni', 'afrykanerskojzyczni'),
    ('abcdefg','xac')
]
```

You can create a function that gives you the HTML string which highlights the insertions, deletions and replacements, using the following code:

```py
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

# highlight colors
# you may change these values according to your preferences
color_delete = '#811612'  # highlight color for deletions
color_insert = '#28862D'  # highlight color for insertions
color_replace = '#BABA26' # highlight color for replacements

# the common format string used for highlighted segments
f_str = '<span style="background: {};">{}</span>'

# given two strings (a, b), getFormattedDiff returns the HTML formatted strings (formatted_a, formatted_b)
def getFormattedDiff(a, b):
    # initialize the sequence matcher
    s = SequenceMatcher(None, a, b)

    # stringbuilders for the formatted strings
    formatted_a = []
    formatted_b = []

    # iterate through all char blocks
    for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in s.get_opcodes():
        if tag == 'equal':
            # if the blovks are the same, append block to both strings without any formatting
            formatted_a.append(a[i1:i2])
            formatted_b.append(b[j1:j2])
        elif tag == 'delete':
            # if this is a deletion block, append block to the first string with the delete highlight
            formatted_a.append(f_str.format(color_delete, a[i1:i2]))
        elif tag == 'insert':
            # if this is a insertion block, append block to the second string with the insert highlight
            formatted_b.append(f_str.format(color_insert, b[j1:j2]))
        elif tag == 'replace':
            # if this is a replacement block, append block to both strings with the replace highlight
            formatted_a.append(f_str.format(color_replace, a[i1:i2]))
            formatted_b.append(f_str.format(color_replace, b[j1:j2]))

    # return the formatted strings
    return ''.join(formatted_a), ''.join(formatted_b)
```

Now we run the above defined function in a loop for all the `cases` strings like so:

```py
from IPython.display import HTML, display

# iterate through all the cases and display both strings with the highlights
for a, b in cases:
    formatted_a, formatted_b = getFormattedDiff(a, b)
    display(HTML(formatted_a))
    display(HTML(formatted_b))
    print()
```

and we get the following display output:

[image]