# Compare Two Different JSON In Python Using Difflib, Showing Only The Differences

Tags: python, python-3.x, diff, difflib

I am trying to compare 2 different pieces of (Javascript/JSON) code using `difflib` module in Python 3.8,

> {"message": "Hello world", "name": "Jack"}

and

> {"message": "Hello world", "name": "Ryan"}

**Problem:** When these 2 strings are prettified and compared using `difflib`, we get the inline differences, as well as all the common lines.

Is there a way to only show the lines that differ, in a manner thats clearer to look at? This will help significantly when both files are much larger in size, making it more challenging to identify the changed lines.

Thanks!

---

**Actual Output**

```
{
    "message": "Hello world",
    "name": "{J -> Ry}a{ck -> n}"
}
```

---

**Desired Output**

```
    "name": "{J -> Ry}a{ck -> n}"
```

Even better will be something like:

```
    {"name": "Jack"} -> {"name": "Ryan"}
```

---

**Python Code Used**

*We use `jsbeautifier` here instead of `json` because the files we are comparing may sometimes be malformed JSON. `json` will throw an error while `jsbeautifier` still formats it the way we expect it to.*

```
import jsbeautifier

def inline_diff(a, b):
    """
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774316/python-difflib-highlighting-differences-inline/47617607#47617607
    """
    import difflib
    matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, b)
    def process_tag(tag, i1, i2, j1, j2):
        if tag == 'replace':
            return '{' + matcher.a[i1:i2] + ' -> ' + matcher.b[j1:j2] + '}'
        if tag == 'delete':
            return '{- ' + matcher.a[i1:i2] + '}'
        if tag == 'equal':
            return matcher.a[i1:i2]
        if tag == 'insert':
            return '{+ ' + matcher.b[j1:j2] + '}'
        assert false, "Unknown tag %r"%tag
    return ''.join(process_tag(*t) for t in matcher.get_opcodes())


# File content to compare
file1 = '{"message": "Hello world", "name": "Jack"}'
file2 = '{"message": "Hello world", "name": "Ryan"}'

# Prettify JSON
f1 = jsbeautifier.beautify(file1)
f2 = jsbeautifier.beautify(file2)

# Print the differences to stdout
print(inline_diff(f1, f2))
```

Answer (score 0):

For your *desired* output you can do even without usage of `difflib`, for example:

```
def find_diff(a, b):
    result = []
    a = json.loads(a)
    b = json.loads(b)
    for key in a:
        if key not in b:
            result.append(f'{dict({key: a[key]})} -> {"key deleted"}')
        elif key in b and a[key] != b[key]:
            result.append(f'{dict({key: a[key]})} -> {dict({key: b[key]})}')
    return '\n'.join(t for t in result)

# File content to compare
file1 = '{"new_message": "Hello world", "name": "Jack"}'
file2 = '{"message": "Hello world", "name": "Ryan"}'

print(find_diff(f1, f2))

#{'new_message': 'Hello world'} -> key deleted
#{'name': 'Jack'} -> {'name': 'Ryan'}
```

There are plenty of ways to handle it, try to adapt it for your needs.